# Рассчитать количество дней между датами с moment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

Есть две даты в таймстемпе. Например

```
const start = 1633046400;
const end = 1640908800;
```

Нужно найти количество дней между ними

Comment: А зачем для этого moment? Если не волнует учёт местных часовых поясов, то просто `(end - start) / 3600 / 24`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const start = 1633046400;
const end = 1640908800;

console.log(
  moment(end * 1000).diff(moment(start * 1000), 'days')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ```moment.unix(end).diff(moment.unix(start), 'days');``` избавился от умножения на 1000